# Unable to Translate large compressed files such as 5GB and 8GB

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

Related with this question : [Upload large zip file(8GB+) for translation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64013572/upload-large-zip-file8gb-for-translation), there question was about our struggling to upload 5/8gb compressed zip. Later we could upload those big models. Now we are trying to [translate](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/developers_guide/basics/translation/) those models to view in forge viewer. We tried several attempts already but seems the posted job crashed immediately after the token expire although our application automatically acquires a new token before expire. Can anyone suggest what step(s) we may take before starting the translation again?
**If anyone interested I can provide urn!**
Thanks in advance!

sample code :

```
job = new JobPayload(new JobPayloadInput(urn, true, mainfile), new JobPayloadOutput(outputs));
  
// start translation 
   
DerivativesApi derivative = new DerivativesApi();
derivative.Configuration.AccessToken = AccessToken;

ApiResponse<dynamic> jobPosted = await derivative.TranslateAsyncWithHttpInfo(job,true);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When translating a design, you only need a valid token when *submitting* the translation job. If the design is too complex, the translation may take a lot of time but there is no need to refresh the access token during that time.

The Model Derivative service can process very large designs as well, so if something goes wrong with the translation, it could be an issue specific to your design. In that case we would recommend sharing the design with us via `forge (dot) help (at) autodesk (dot) com` so that we could debug the translation on our side.

Comment: you are correct. In the main rvt model file,out of 32 linked files seems 1 have issue.We removed that link file from the model and uploaded model again (which is 7gb), and translation went well only it took 3 hrs!. Now we are checking that issue file. Think we can solve that also. Important is our pressure released ! We thought Forge can't handle such big files but at the end actually we are wrong ! Thanks again for your concern/comments and have a very good day.

Comment: BTW: @Petr Broz, I accepted your above comments as answer.  [here i also replied on your comment] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64013572/upload-large-zip-file8gb-for-translation)